# SpringMethodInvocationBean: Argument is an Interface

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, el

```
<bean id="arrayDescriptor"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject">
        <value>oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor</value>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>createDescriptor</value>
    </property>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>UDB_NAME</value>
            <value>#{database.getConnection()}</value>
        </list> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

I can't seem to make the method work because it needs an argument of (String, java.sql.Connection) instead its getting (String, org.basic.datasource.PoolableConnection).

Is it possible to typecast on EL? I have research its not possible.
Can I use another spring api to run a method and an argument?
Is it possible to instantiate in Spring at interface? I have research and it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the [`ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/ArrayDescriptor.html) requires `DataSource`, not a connection. I guess `database` represents `DataSource`, try:

```
<value>#{database}</value>
```

or even:

```
<ref bean="database"/>
```

What about using Java configuration and avoiding this XML hell?

```
@Configuration
public class Cfg {

    @Resource
    private DataSource database;

    @Bean
    public ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor() {
        return ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("UDB_NAME", database);
    }
}
```